# Jetty, multiple applications on server

Tags: java, memory, jetty

I currently have an application running with Jetty (version 8.1.3). I would like to create an additional version for a different client environment on the same server.

Is there a risk of memory overhead on the server? or other? The two applications used the same database.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a risk of memory overhead on the server?"

From the Jetty standpoint, unlikely to be a risk, it generally occupies a very small footprint when compared to the applications deployed into it.

From your application standpoint, only you can determine that.  You must compute your applications memory needs and what it may scale to in order to make this determination.  You need to sort out a high water mark for memory needs for your application, double that and round up a bit to then decide if you have both the processing and memory available to do it.  Remember your thread requirements as well, double the connection pooling (or are you sharing the pool with server wise jndi pools) and is your database going to be fine with that, the number of open files on the server allowed, etc, etc.

So long story short, there is no definitely yes or no answer available from a site like stackoverflow on this, it depends too much on your specific application and amount of traffic you have.  Knowing that information however will let you have confidence on if you can do this or not.